# Saving a File With SavePanel with Custom UTI

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3, nssavepanel

I often create my own document type for my desktop applications.  But I have never registered my own custom UTI.  Anyway, I want to save a simple `Dictionary` data as a data (`NSData`) file like the following.

```
@IBAction func testClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let savePath = self.documentPath() // setting a default path
    let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
    savePanel.directoryURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: savePath)
    savePanel.title = ""
    savePanel.message = ""
    savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "File"
    savePanel.showsHiddenFiles = false
    savePanel.showsTagField = false
    savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    savePanel.allowsOtherFileTypes = false
    savePanel.allowedFileTypes = ["customtype"]
    savePanel.isExtensionHidden = false
    if savePanel.runModal() == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
        let dict = ["title": "New York Nightly News", "url": "http://www.newyorknightlynews.net/cmlink/TopNews.rss"] as Dictionary<String, String>
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dict)
        do {
            try data.write(to: savePanel.url!, options: .atomic)
        }
        catch {

        }
    } else {
        print("canceled")
    }
}
```

[image]

I have set up a document type and an exported UTI as shown above.

Initially, I set the `UTTypeConformsTo` type to `public.data`.  But I've changed it to `public.xml` and `public.text`.  Yet, an exported file has no file icon.  It doesn't appear that my custom UTI is correctly recognized.  My goal is to let this desktop application produces a file such that the user can send it to an iOS equivalent through AirDrop.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Does it work without the save panel?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  My iOS app does accept a file if I change the file type to xml, though.

Comment: So the save panel has nothing to do with it? Maybe you should change the title to attract icon/UTI specialists.